# Does an extension receipt in combination with a copy of an expired green card serve as a proof of a legal status?

Tags: legal

Based on [this article](https://www.uscis.gov/newsroom/alerts/uscis-extends-green-card-validity-for-conditional-permanent-residents-with-a-pending-form-i-751-or) “`These receipt notices can be presented with an expired Green Card as evidence of continued status, while the case remains pending with USCIS`.”

So in order to prove your legal status, you need the receipt and the **actual physical card**. What if you misplace it? Does a copy of your card and the receipt serve as a proof of legal status? Could you please provide links to the formal “.gov” legal articles explaining this?

Comment: "is there any official law stating if I’m legally present" (from a comment on a deleted answer): I doubt you will find a single law, but if you find all the ways a conditional LPR can lose permanent resident status, you'll see that losing the card isn't among them.

Answer (score 2):

You need both the I-751 receipt and the actual expired green card to function as valid proof of permanent residency. A copy doesn't count, just like how a copy of a lost unexpired green card cannot function as a valid green card. If either is lost, then you do not have valid proof of permanent residency, though you remain in permanent resident status.

Not having proof of status will likely not affect you in your daily life, if you don't leave the US or go near a border where they have immigration checkpoints, but as an adult foreigner, you are required by law to carry proof of permanent residency with you at all times, so it's a good idea to get new proof of permanent residency.

Conditional permanent residents cannot file I-90 to replace a green card after their 2-year card has expired or is within 90 days of expiring. See [I-90 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-90instr.pdf):

> Conditional permanent residents may not use this application to replace, for any reason, an existing Permanent Resident Card that is expired or will expire within 90 days.

So the only proof of permanent residency you can get in this situation is an I-551 stamp. You should contact USCIS and inform them that you have a pending I-751 but your expired green card is lost, and therefore you need an I-551 stamp (ADIT stamp) as temporary proof of permanent residency. The I-551 stamp will serve as a standalone proof of permanent residency equivalent to a green card (the green card is just an I-551 document), without needing the extension letter. I believe the I-551 stamp is valid for one year. At the end of that, if your I-751 is still pending, you would again request an I-551 stamp if you want proof of permanent residency.